# Public data about a website I do not own

Tags: analytics, visitors, web-traffic

I am looking at a competitors site. The site is technologically advanced but I do not believe it is efficient in converting visitors to customers.

I would like to look at any publically available data about the website so that I can get a grasp on how the competitor is doing online.

Where can I get the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Unless they share their data with you or publish it the best you can do is guess. The closest you can get is Alexa but their data is not accurate and gets worse as you get further away from the top sites.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Is there any usable data that is publicly available?

Comment: Not conversion data. Just backlink, keyword, a guess at traffic etc. There are websites for this, but most including the best fall short of being accurate and most of the good ones want you to verify you own the site.